# Xamarin iOS Authorization Header with UIWebView request

Tags: xamarin, uiwebview, xamarin.ios

I would like to add a Authorization header with the url i am calling to load a UIWebView.
Same thing which is done using ObjC like this

```c
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData     base64EncodingWithLineLength:80]];
[theRequest setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

I tried in Xamarin some thing like but it is not the Authorization header.

```cs
var req = new NSMutableUrlRequest(new NSUrl(urlStr));
var keys = new object[] { "Token"};
var objects = new object[] { tokenVal};
var dictionnary = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(objects, keys);
req.Headers = dictionnaire;
```

I don't see NSMutableUrlRequest has forHTTPHeaderField property to set.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for an answer to this.
So for anybody trying to do that, the iOS webview actually has a "Header" property, on which you can call "SetValueForKey".

```cs
 var request = new NSMutableUrlRequest();
 request.Headers.SetValueForKey(new NSString("MyHeaderValue"), new NSString("MyHeaderKey"));
```

Comment: Header and Value are inverted for method `SetValueForKey`, value comes first. Tiny confusion.